# Need a help with the first order linear vector recurrence relation.

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

I have a sequence of vectors $\{\psi_{k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $\psi_{k}\in{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$ and they obey the following linear recurrence relation
$$\psi_{n}=c_{n-1}\psi_{n-1}$$
Where
$$c_{k}\in{M_{2\times{2}}(\mathbb{C})}$$
I had the following idea. We multiply the relation by 
$$\prod_{k=-\infty}^{n-1}c_{k}^{-1}$$
To give
$$\prod_{k=-\infty}^{n-1}c_{k}^{-1}\psi_{n}=\prod_{k=-\infty}^{n-2}c_{k}^{-1}\psi_{n-1}$$
Then we call 
$$\chi_{n}=\prod_{k=-\infty}^{n-1}c_{k}^{-1}\psi_{n}$$
So, the reccurence becomes
$$\chi_{n}=\chi_{n-1}$$
Hence
$$\chi_{n}=\chi, \ \forall{n}$$
Where $\chi$ is some constant vector. So, that
$$\psi_{n}=\Big(\prod_{k=-\infty}^{n-1}c_{k}^{-1}\Big)^{-1}\chi$$
Can anyone give it a sober look, and, perhaps, find some mistakes. Pre-thanks!!!